# New Windows Service Application version won't start

Tags: .net, windows, service

I have a windows service that has been running.  I have created a new version of the application.  I went to the windows server and stopped the service.  I then copied in the new .exe for the service and tried to start the service.  The service won't start, it times out trying to start and I can't figure out why.  I am positive that I have done this before.  Do I  need to uninstall the service and reinstall it?

Server: Windows Server 2003 R2
Application .NET Version: 2.0
Developed With: VS 2005
Language VB.NET

OnStart Method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

InitializeComponent:
CHECKDB_INTERVAL_TIME = 10

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim iWaitTime As Int16
    iWaitTime = CType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CHECKDB_INTERVAL_TIME"), Int16)
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
    Me.Timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer()
    Me.Timer1.Interval = iWaitTime * 60000
    '
    'HarleyCloser
    '
    Me.ServiceName = "MyService"

End Sub

Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer
```

I found the issue.  The problem was with a directive that was being used to do something different in Debug mode versus Release mode.

Comment: Any error messages in the Event viewer?

Comment: What does the *Application Log* in *Event Viewer* say?

Comment: If the event viewer says nothing, one thing I've found helpful is to add event log entries or messages to a database while debugging - things like "About to call DoSomeWork..." and "DoSomeWork Completed"... etc.  Particularly in loops that contain processes that could take some time to complete.  It's really the only way I've figured out to debug a service applicaiton easily.  It lets you see where, in the code, the service is hanging or taking longer than expected.

Comment: Now that I've said that, I just thought of googling how to debug a Windows service, and of course, Microsoft has a potentially better way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @David Stratton I think you still only get 30 seconds to step through the code before the service manager terminates the service.

Comment: In my experience, the service manager often reports that it "could not start the service" but the service continues to start.  I have one service in particular, that processes files on a server and transfers them to a DB.  If it's been down for more than an hour, it has a lot of catch-up work to do.  Without fail, I will start the service, see an error message that says "Unable to start the service" but check and the files are still being processed and the service is running.  I then go back about 20 minutes later, refresh the status, and see that it's running.

Comment: So I can say with confidence that the service should still be running, and the debugger should still be able to attach, even if the Service Manager has given you an "Unable to start service" message UNLESS something truly is crashing the service, such as an unhandled exception. (IN which case there should automatically be an event log.)

Comment: @Adam, can you post the code you used to set up Timer1 too?

Comment: What is the Timer interval set for, and again, what type of timer is this? There are three types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: The Timer is set as: Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer

Comment: I found the Issue.  There was some code hidden in the service with a Debug Directive.  If the service was compiled in Debug then it ran like a console application, if it was compiled in Release, then it ran as a service.  So the Service was timing out on the OnStart because it was trying to run the whole console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue. There was some code hidden in the service with a Debug Directive. If the service was compiled in Debug then it ran like a console application, if it was compiled in Release, then it ran as a service. So the Service was timing out on the OnStart because it was trying to run the whole console application.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the service exe you really should uninstall the previous one and install the new one.  And oftentimes you'll need to reboot to complete the uninstall before you can install the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the service, replacing the exe and re-starting it should be fine, I have done this many times.

Something you changed between versions put a task that takes a long time in your OnStart. OnStart must go from start to finish in under 30 seconds. Check your OnStart code for something that is blocking.

If you need to debug OnStart [here is some tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on what to do, however the 30 second limit still applies. Another tip is put some logging messages in to OnStart that will add messages to the windows log showing how far your code has gotten.

Comment: I am using a timer and I enable the timer in the OnStart event.  Will this fire and possibly cause a time out while the service is trying to start?

Comment: What kind of timer, there are several in the .net framework. The most useful thing you can do is post the entire OnStart method in your original question as a edit. Just paste it, highlight it and click the `{ }` button to format it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use "installutil" to uninstall the old service and then again to install the new one. You can use "installutil" via Visual Studio Command Prompt.

As a side note, if the OnStart method of your service takes a long time to execute, you might want to start a timer that does all the work, inside that OnStart method.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the installutil to install and uninstall. ALWAYS, replacing the .EXE is not a good approach.

You must also check the user under which the service is executed.  By default I think its local service which doesnt have a lot of privileges, you can set the user by code or using the services snap in.

this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User; this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"]; this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["username"];